# Linq2Sql results availability timeout

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis

I use Linq2Sql to retrieve a list of ID's that I use to launch a SSRS report export wia SSRS web service.
The query retrieves about 200 items and I use a foreach loop to loop through them.

I pass the List object containing the ID's to a method executed *in a new thread*.

The SSRS report generation is quite long, so sometimes when the server goes slower due to work load, the overall execution execeedes the *20 minutes* and my threads ends, with no exception.

Is there a timeout setting in Linq2Sql DataContext that matches this use case, after which my results become unavailable and the foreach loop ends?

**Update 1 (the code):**

```
List<String> list = dc.ListaIDs().ToList<String>();
int count = 0;
foreach (var item in list)
{
    string FileName = "report_" + (++count).ToString() + ".pdf";
    LoggerUtility.Instance.log.Debug(String.Format("export => " + FileName));
    try
    {
        switch (ReportFormat)
        {
            case "PDF":
                risultato = ReportServiceImpl.WSReport("PDF", item);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(FileName, risultato.PDFResult);
                break;
            default:
                LoggerUtility.Instance.log.Warn("no format");
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LoggerUtility.Instance.log.Warn("error exporting => " + FileName, ex);
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

The rs object (of a custom ReportService class I made to separate report WS calls) is not in the same scope of the thread; it's declared and instantiated outside the method launched as a thread and the class containing the method and the rs declaration is an MVC 3 controller.

In the ReportService class every call instantiates a new ReportExecutionService (previously obtained by a web reference to ReportExecution2005.asmx).

**Update 3 (the WS call code and a little update in the first part of code):**

I refactored the code to have a static call to my `ReportServiceImpl`'s method and applying what's told in @JamieSee's response that may exclude timeout in Linq2Sql.
This is the ReportServiceImpl.WSReport actual implementation; after 20 minutes it stops without exceptions at `result = service.Render(...)`:

```
public static ReportResult WSReport(String format, string id)
{
    ReportResult _return = new ReportResult();
    ReportExecution.ReportExecutionService service = null;
    try
    {
        byte[] result;
        service = new ReportExecution.ReportExecutionService();

        String reportPath = @"/myReport";
        string historyID = null;

        service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        //load report
        ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
        ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();

        service.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;
        execInfo = service.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID);

        //set execution parameter
        ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[1];
        parameters[0] = new ParameterValue() { Name = "id", Value = id };
        service.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "it-IT");

        String SessionId = service.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;

        //render report actually
        String deviceInfo = "";
        String extension;
        String mimetype;
        String encoding;
        GestioneVIP_Services.ReportExecution.Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        result = service.Render(format, deviceInfo, out extension, out mimetype, out encoding, out warnings, out streams);
        switch (format)
        {
            case Constants.EXCEL_FORMAT:
                _return.XLSResult = result;
                break;
            case Constants.PDF_FORMAT:
                _return.PDFResult = result;
                break;
            case Constants.HTML_FORMAT:
                _return.HTMLResult = result;
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (SoapException ex)
    {
        LoggerUtility.Instance.log.Error(String.Format("{0}/n{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LoggerUtility.Instance.log.Error(String.Format("{0}/n{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (service != null)
        {
            service.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return _return;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error that you're seeing? It's possible that you're hitting the session timeout for the report server. I'd also try opening a web browser on the report server and running the report from there as it tends to produce more detailed error messages than a non-local session. Also, if it's taking 20 minutes to deal with only 200 items, you may have a design problem with the report. I don't typically see 20 minute execution times until I'm dealing with hundreds of thousands of items.

Comment: I have my foreach loop in a try...catch block, but no execptions are thrown. I see thread stopping (stop logging) at 20 minutes since it's started. If the server load is low I can complete the job (within 20 minutes).

Comment: If you are launching new threads inside the try/catch block, you won't catch any exceptions. The launched threads don't bubble exceptions up to the caller. What method of threading are you using? Can you post some code?

Comment: Updated the question with code. Note: I call the SSRS via web service (through the rs object in the code).

Comment: Try changing `IEnumerable<String> list = dc.ListaIDs();` to `List<string> list = dc.ListaIDs().ToList();`. That should avoid deferred execution in the foreach and will tell you if it was a Linq problem or something else.

Comment: Good suggestion. If you write it as an answer I'll upvote this and comment there; however I gave it a try and it doesn't solve the problem. I'll go on trying to solve this.

Comment: Put comment as answer, I'll look for your comments to see what I may be able to suggest further.

Comment: Also, can you show your code for the WSReport method? Given your description of what it does, I still think that threading may be swallowing exceptions.

Comment: Ok... I don't actually see a new thread getting started anywhere here. However, I do wonder if your logger may not be logging. Have you tried putting `throw;` in your catch blocks and commenting out the logger lines temporarily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing with the multiple thread configuration mentioned in a comment above and going deeper into this issue, I found the correct answer to it, so I'm reporting it here for completeness.

The reason for this subtle timeout, resides in the *Idle Time-out* configuration in the *Process Model* section of the *Advanced Settings* of the *Application Pool*.

It's default value is **20 minutes**.

For some reason that I yet don't understand, a process initiated from the web layer that launches some threads, if there's no web layer activity is treated as Idle and then stopped. It can be seen even following the behaviour of the *w3wp.exe* process in the *Processes* tab in *Task Manager*.
Any threads, queued in a ThreadPool or launched directly by this process will end with the process.

At the end I can say it's not Linq2Sql related and not SRSS web services related, but more IIS process model related.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing IEnumerable list = dc.ListaIDs(); to List list = dc.ListaIDs().ToList();. That should avoid deferred execution in the foreach and will tell you if it was a Linq problem or something else.

Comment: Thanks JamieSee. You helped. Finally I eneded with launchin one thread per report instead of a thread retrieving all records. Not tested yet, and not yet understood the reason for the timeout.

Comment: I've unaccepted your answer, though it was of some help, because I finally found the correct underlying reason for the behaviour illustrated in the question. I've posted it as an answer below.